# Acer Laptop Win10 Upgraded to v1703 OS version: Fn Key not working after upgrade

Tags: acer-aspire, windows-10-v1703, fn-key

Acer Laptop(Aspire V5 571p) Win10 v1511/1607 OS Upgrade to Win10 v1703 OS version: Fn Key not working after the upgrade.

Comment: Did you check any keyboard driver issue?

Comment: Wet noodles of tags.  Only three are really relevant so I got rid of them.

Comment: Other keys are working fine. I am not sure its keyboard issue only.

Answer (score -1):

I know the Fn key can be disabled in some BIOS settings, but I do not suspect the BIOS since all you did was an OS upgrade.  I would check the BIOS anyways before going further.

I suspect the new Windows update may have installed "UEFI only" devices, UEFI only during boot is more secure if the entire system is configured to only boot UEFI drivers, which do not always play well with some older legacy keyboards and mice. In BIOS you may want to enable legacy support, compatibility support module, or Auto. Some systems are set to UEFI only, set it to Legacy first, then UEFI.

Comment: OP does not mention BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: @Biswa - OP does not mention BIOS/UEFI , most users who experience issues will normally not be able to mention possible remedies for resolution, or possible troubleshooting steps otherwise they would not be asking for help. Fn key settings can be found in the majority of BIOS settings. Microsoft has been moving to UEFI for years now to replace legacy hardware, any updates/upgrades applied to Windows recently that result in hardware failure can usually be attributed to compatibility issues from the updates. Fn keys on legacy drivers are easily exploited during POST to install keylogger malware.

Comment: @Slapdog: Can you please guide the steps to check and enabling Legacy support and UEFI in the mentioned acer model as above.

Comment: UEFI has the same role as bios. Windows does not 'install' UEFI, and its unlikely a classic bios can be replaced with UEFI.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek All depends on the MOBO manufacture and product lifetime for support. UEFI is supposed to replace the BIOS eventually but the rollout is a disaster.BIOS had a few simple functions/limited customization,but was less vulnerable,now UEFI has dozens of features which attackers have exploited by targeting those features to compromise the system.This is the event of the year for Security pro's.MOBOs still dual wield UEFI/BIOS for compatibility.But for complete security UEFI must be universal,TPM enabled,SecBoot, legacy device need to be digitally signed and verified online.

Comment: @venkat I will edit my answer shortly,not sure why I did not receive notice of your response. Please reply if the issue still persists as I may need you to provide me with a log to verify your hardware version with msinfo32.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You are correct,Windows does not update the BIOS/UEFI, I corrected my answer. I meant to say that Windows will update drivers to UEFI specs now and then as legacy support is fading for peripherals.The Fn key is targeted,because it can be exploited to control the keyboard making the user mis-type passwords or assume the keyboard is broken,this allows keylogger attacks and packet retrieval during re-authentication attempts.The OP's question is not adequate,but I have seen this before.There is an option in many BIOS/UEFI for Fn key functions.Just need the check the version 1st.

Comment: “The OP's question is not adequate” - Then the question should be improved by the author of the question or you should find a similar but higher quality question to answer instead.